# How do I declare and run an anonymous plpgsql block in liquibase

Tags: plpgsql, liquibase

I am running liquibase changelog with changeset definition and anonymous plpgsql block as described below , while executing i get sql syntax exception .I am not able to find the correct syntax to use for this.

Database changelog :

```
    <changeSet author="wamk" id="20210909102601">
    
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <dbms type="postgresql" />
        </preConditions>
    
        <sqlFile path="027-rename-psps.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" endDelimiter="/" dbms="PostgreSQL" encoding="utf8" splitStatements="true"/>
    </changeSet>
    
</databaseChangeLog>
```

'027-rename-psps.sql' file contents :

```
declare
   cur_rename cursor (modulekeyold varchar) for 
    select * from payment_module_config where module_key = modulekeyold;    
counter integer = 0;
commitnum integer = 100;
begin
    FOR recordvar IN cur_rename('WirecardPaymentService_1.0') loop
      raise notice 'Value: %', recordvar;
      UPDATE payment_module_config SET module_key='GetNet V1'  WHERE id = recordvar.id;
      counter = counter + 1;
      if(counter%commitnum=0) then
         raise notice '>>>   counter: %', counter;
         commit;
      end if;  
    end loop;
   commit;
end;
/
```

EXCEPTION :

```
12:26:23.933 [main] ERROR liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet - Change Set db/changelog/027-rename-psps.sql::raw::includeAll failed.  Error: Syntax error in SQL statement "DECLARE
   CUR_RENAME[*] CURSOR (MODULEKEYOLD VARCHAR) FOR 
    SELECT * FROM PAYMENT_MODULE_CONFIG WHERE MODULE_KEY = MODULEKEYOLD;    
COUNTER INTEGER = 0;
COMMITNUM INTEGER = 100;
BEGIN ...
```

Comment: What is the Liquibase version, exact liquibase command,  jdbc driver and what postgres database community (aws ,opensource, EDB, etc ) that you are using to run this?

We tried the same code as you provided above, and we ran it successfully.Here's my setup for PostgreSQL:
Liquibase version 4.4.3
Postgres driver: postgresql-42.2.23.jar
Connecting to a Postgres Community

Answer (score 1):

I get the same problem and the solution is here. You must put "runWith:psql attribute on your changeset, but this only available in Liquibase PRO version: [Liquibase PRO documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/use-psql-integration.html#runWith)

```
--Liquibase formatted sql

--changeset POPULATE_NPS_CONFIG:1 runWith:psql
DECLARE
    vId UUID;
BEGIN
    vId := gen_random_uuid();

    INSERT INTO NPS_CONFIG (
        ID, EXECUTION, RANGES, RANGES_COLORS
    ) VALUES (
        vId, '2023-03-01', '-100-0,1-50,51-75,76-100', '#FF0000;#00FF00;#0000FF'
    );
```